Panel in wheel well for rear driver wheel, what is it for and is it easy to remove?
2013 Dodge Grand Caravan
Due to an emergency on the road, I ended up turning onto a side street. I didn't realize until too late that this was a dirt road, and muddy from recent rain to boot. I managed fine, but now when I close the metal panel over my fuel cap, I get the sound of dirt falling somewhere inside my van, and I sometimes get "fuel cap" warnings despite it being attached tightly.
When I checked out the area below my fuel inlet, I noticed that there's a panel separate from the main structure of the wheel well, and there's a large enough hole at the top of it that mud could easily have made it in after being sprayed up by my tire. See pictures below. When I reach in to that hole, I can definitely feel some dirt clods in there.
Is this panel easy to remove (once the wheel has been pulled off)? Like, could I with little mechanic experience remove the panel myself, clean out behind it, and then reinstall the panel?


